# Error while installing Moodle 29

Tags: moodle

I have place moodle files: C:\xampp\htdocs\moodle, E:\moodledata and in mysql created database "moodle".I m getting this **error message** on the webpage  when opening moodle

"Config table does not contain version, can not continue, sorry.

More information about this error

It is usually not possible to recover from errors triggered during installation, you may need to create a new database or use a different database prefix if you want to retry the installation."

**Setting in config.php**

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mysqli';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodle';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'root';
$CFG->dbpass    = '';
$CFG->prefix    = 'lms_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbsocket' => '',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/moodle';

$CFG->dataroot  = 'E:\\moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/setup.php');

// There is no php closing tag in this file,
// it is intentional because it prevents trailing whitespace problems!
```

Comment: Are you trying to install a new moodle, or upgrade from an older version?

Comment: trying to install new moodle 29

Comment: Sounds like it's got stuck somewhere, have you tried wiping your moodle database of anything it tried to install and trying it again?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it got interrupted during install and now the database is incomplete. You can try two things: insert the missing version number into the config table, for example by using phpMyAdmin, or delete the database, create a new one and try to install again.

To insert the version number:

- open the file version.php to find the version number.
- in your database manager, go to the table mdl_config
- insert a new record with the values: name='version' and value='*the version number you looked up in the version.php file*'

Answer (score -1):

this can happen if the install process is not perfect.
You haven't told us the version or anything about the 'local server'
so we can not see the specifics of your problem.

check the release notes for the version you are using and make sure 100% that your server meets the requirements.